# Finding the history of my 1980s Norco Bike

Tags: history

Where can I find a Norco catalog from 198X?  I bought a used Norco about 10 months ago and I am begining to get curious about the bike.  How good of bike is it?  How much did it cost new?  Where was it made?  Etc.

Anyone know where I can find an older, 1980s, Norco catalog?  Are there other resources that I could use to find out about my bike?

*Meta: I don't think that I can post a picture of my bike here and ask for information on it can I?*

Comment: Of course you can post a picture of your bike, as long as it relates to the question in question. The  problem you need solved is that you want information about your bike. Posting a picture is just a way of conveying information towards that end. (The Bikeforums [classic and vintage forum](http://www.bikeforums.net/forumdisplay.php/181-Classic-amp-Vintage) might also be able to help, if you don't get an answer here.) And, dude, we're talking about pictures. Of **bikes**.

Comment: you can put pictures on imgur.
Make certain you take pictures of the whole bike and closeups of the different components.

Answer (score 5):

Norco is still around. You could probably start by getting in touch with someone there.

http://www.norco.com/

Answer (score 2):

Norco and Nishiki of this era were really the same bike. The company that imported them in the U.S. and Canada did so under two different names so that they could manipulate the market more effectively.

Many of these frames were manufactured by Kawamura of Japan.  The serial numbering schema has been worked out by some bicycle geeks.  If you can find the serial number on your bike (usually stamped on the bottom bracket housing or sometimes on the chainstay), this might be helpful:  http://www.bikeforums.net/showthread.php/390318-Nishiki-Serial-Number-Database?highlight=nishiki

If the numbers make no sense whatsoever, it's because not all of these bikes were manufactured by Kawamura.  A large number were, though, so I offer the link!  Good luck.